# need help switching music background on my pygame code

Tags: python, audio, pygame

I am trying to switch background music when the pictures
hits bottom and back to the first one when it hits the top. When
I try to put it in the `while #formula` then it just resets every time
it descends a little and that is not what i want.
Can you help me in figuring how to put this code:

```
pygame.mixer.music.load('song1')
pygame.mixer.music.play(-1, 0.0)

pygame.mixer.music.load('song2')
pygame.mixer.music.play(-1, 0.0)
```

inside the code below and make it switch as I explained it here?
If I forgot to explain something that you need to know 
please let me know.

```
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()

FPS = 200
fpsClock = pygame.time.Clock()

DISPLAYSURF = pygame.display.set_mode((400, 400), 0, 0)
pygame.display.set_caption('Verkefni 21')

WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
clownx = 10
clowny = 10
direction = 'right'
stefna = 'niður'

while True:
DISPLAYSURF.fill(WHITE)
if stefna == 'niður':
    if direction == 'right':
        clownImg = pygame.image.load('sarah.jpg')
        clownx += 5
        if clownx == 320:
            clowny += 10
            direction = 'left'
            clownImg = pygame.image.load('john.jpg')
        if clowny == 300:
            stefna = 'up'
            soundObj = pygame.mixer.Sound('bomb.wav')
            soundObj.play()
            import time
            time.sleep(2) # wait and let the sound play for 1 second
            soundObj.stop()

    elif direction == 'left':
        clownImg = pygame.image.load('john.jpg')
        clownx -= 5
        if clownx == 10:
            clowny += 10
            direction = 'right'
            clownImg = pygame.image.load('sarah.jpg')
        if clowny == 300:
            stefna = 'up'
            soundObj = pygame.mixer.Sound('bomb.wav')
            soundObj.play()
            import time
            time.sleep(2) # wait and let the sound play for 1 second
            soundObj.stop()
elif stefna == 'up':
    if direction == 'right':
        clownImg = pygame.image.load('arnold.jpg')
        clownx += 5
        if clownx == 320:
            clowny -= 10
            direction = 'left'
            clownImg = pygame.image.load('terminator.jpg')
        if clowny == 0:
            stefna = 'niður'
            soundObj = pygame.mixer.Sound('bomb.wav')
            soundObj.play()
            import time
            time.sleep(2) # wait and let the sound play for 1 second
            soundObj.stop()
    elif direction == 'left':
        clownImg = pygame.image.load('terminator.jpg')
        clownx -= 5
        if clownx == 0:
            clowny -=10
            direction = 'right'
            clownImg = pygame.image.load('arnold.jpg')
        if clowny == 0:
            stefna = 'niður'
            soundObj = pygame.mixer.Sound('bomb.wav')
            soundObj.play()
            import time
            time.sleep(2) # wait and let the sound play for 1 second
            soundObj.stop()

DISPLAYSURF.blit(clownImg, (clownx, clowny))

for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == QUIT:
        pygame.quit()
        sys.exit()

pygame.display.update()
fpsClock.tick(FPS)
```

Answer (score 2):

Put `pygame.mixer.music.stop()` when you switch songs.

Answer (score 0):

```
pygame.mixer.music.stop()

pygame.mixer.music.unload()

pygame.mixer.music.load(os.path.abspath('put your music path here'))

pygame.mixer.music.play(loops=-1, start=0.0, fade_ms=750)

*loops = -1 if you want repeat mode on, loops = 0 to turn repeat mode off
```